# Trying to figure out how to disappear my invisible div from navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a navigation bar, really simple,  figure out alone how to do it but there is something that give me a headache. Let me show you my code before explaining it further :

HTML:

```
<div id="navBar">
<ul class="tiles">  
<li class="tile">
<div class="invDiv">Test</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JQuery/Js:

```
$('.tile').mouseenter(function(){
$('.invDiv').show();
});

$('.tile').mouseout(function(){
$('.invDiv').hide();
});
```

That's it, reallllly simple. So when my mouse go out of my first li and go directly on my div, the div disapear. Well okay, it's because of my mouseout function on .tile...I understand that, but how can I put a condition that goes like this : If my .invDiv is at display:block, then group up .tile + .invDiv. Make disappear .invDiv only when you are out of .invDiv or .tile...but even then, if my mouse is inside my .invDiv and I go on my .tile, that .invDiv disappear! I know it's about a condition but how to write it?!

(I hope y'all understand me, I'm not that good in english!!! thank you everyone.)

Comment: IIRC using div's inside lists is not valid HTML. Anyone that can confirm?

Comment: No thats ok. Li can have block elements as children.

Comment: You have to be a little bit more specific. what exaclty is this innvDiv for? is it the submenu.. then where is the parent link?

Comment: my div navBar is my navigator bar where each li has a submenu in a div block element named invDiv. I didn't put any CSS, for that I am sorry. I know it seems a little bit confusing without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have understood your question i think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/KX76m/3/

```
$('.tile').mouseover(function(){
$('.invDiv').show();
});

$('.tile').mouseout(function(){
$('.invDiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: I knew it it was that simple!! + There is no js condition at all, this is great! Thank you!

Comment: Okay. I know what I did wrong. When I tried it earlier this morning, I put "mouseenter" instead of "mouseover" exactly as your first line. If you put "mouseenter", then your invisible div will disappear even if you come back on your initial position (in this case, first li) Your third function is now useless!

Comment: yep you are right.I was trying to fix the earlier code and forgot to rmove it while saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .toggle() function

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$('.tile').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.invDiv').toggle();
});

$('.tile').mouseout(function(){
    $('.invDiv').toggle();
});
```

A better way to write this code is:

```
$('.tile').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.invDiv').toggle();
});

$('.tile').on('mouseout',function(){
    $('.invDiv').toggle();
});
```

So you don't have any problems if you change somenthing in this div

Comment: I tested it and there is an issue. When your mouse is moving inside the ".invDiv", this Div disappear and reappear constantly. But thanks anyway :)